# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I am trying to read .mat file and save all arrays in .txt format. I have been trying to write it in .txt file but after sometime I get this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to see the reason and came to know that in this .mat file I have an array which is like this

```
array([array(['丰田Avalon'], dtype='<U8')], dtype=object)
```

and I'm pretty sure the error is because of this. But can't find how can I convert it into .txt format to get rid of this error. My code is

```
import os
import scipy.io as cio

mat = cio.loadmat("D:/compCarsThesisData/data/misc/make_model_name.mat")
model_names = mat['model_names']

path = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/"
count = 0
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
  cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
  for f in files:
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if(ext==".jpg"):
      cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
      # print(model_names[int(cip.split('\\')[5])])
      # print("Folder:",cip.split('\\')[4])
      # print("Folder Inside:",cip.split('\\')[5])
      f = open("car_modelss.txt", "a")
      model_names[1369][0][0].encode('utf-8') #here at this I get the specific array which I tried to convert hardcoded.
      f.write((str(model_names[int(cip.split('\\')[5])-1])))
      f.write("Folder: %d\r\n" % (int(cip.split('\\')[4])))
      f.write("Folder Inside: %d\r\n" % (int(cip.split('\\')[5])))
      count = count + 1
      print(count)

f.close()
```

please help

Comment: What's the encoding of the file? What are the actual bytes around position 9?

Comment: @tripleee How can I check it that? Unfortunately, I am new to python also, All I know that it is .mat file having array of arrays containing strings in it. Just like I mentioned above.

Comment: Viewing the file in a hex dump program would at least let you see what bytes are before the text Avalon. Just a few bytes ought to be enough to at least disambiguate the question.